# Transparent decompression of stream

Tags: python, compression, gzip

How do I read a file in Python that may or may not be gzip-compressed?

My current code

```
with gzip.open("file.xml") as f:
    xml.sax.parse(f, reader)
```

works with `.xml.gz` files but not with `.xml` files:

```
...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 409, in _read_gzip_header
    raise OSError('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)
```

Is there a **built-in** or **importable** substitute for the `gzip.open()` call that always returns an uncompressed stream based on file contents and/or file extension?

The answers to the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16813267/946850) would solve my problem, but I'm looking for a packaged solution that doesn't involve any extra code.

Comment: @Flint: Yeah, I'm looking for a "batteries included" solution to that question.

Comment: There's nothing built-in, but what do you against using 8-9 lines of code to open a given file correctly?

Comment: @martineau: I'd accept this as an answer. Hopefully this will give someone an incentive to implement a packaged solution, even if it's just 8-9 lines of code. (bzip2? magic header support? stream support? ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the function defined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16816627/355230) to a related question:

```
import gzip

def opener(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    if f.read(2) == '\x1f\x8b':
        f.seek(0)
        return gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f)
    else:
        f.seek(0)
        return f
```

You can also extend it to support other file formats.